# WPF Path - blurry circle

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to sharpen out pixels in a circle, in WPF ? I tried with SnapToDevicePixels and UseLayoutRounding, but I'm hoping for even better solution.

```
  <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Nazaj na začetno stran"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                    <Path Name="_path" Data="M9 -15.75A7.875000000000002 7.875000000000002 0 1 1 9 0A7.875000000000002 7.875000000000002 0 0 1 9 -15.75zM9 -16.875A9 9 0 1 1 9 1.125A9 9 0 0 1 
                                              9 -16.875z M13.5 -7.875A0.5625 0.5625 0 0 0 12.9375 -8.4375H6.420375L8.83575 -10.85175A0.5625 0.5625 0 0 0 8.03925 -11.64825L4.66425 -8.27325A0.5625 
                                              0.5625 0 0 0 4.66425 -7.47675L8.03925 -4.10175A0.5625 0.5625 0 1 0 8.83575 -4.89825L6.420375 -7.3125H12.9375A0.5625 0.5625 0 0 0 13.5 -7.875z"
                                              Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill"  Width="25" Height="25" />
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                        <Setter TargetName="_path" Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
                                    </Trigger>
                               </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

Button looks like this (blurry circle even on this size):
[image: Output button - WPF path is blurry]

Comment: I don't know the answer but to solve the problem you can use Stroke like this : `Stroke="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"  StrokeThickness="0.5"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how sharp an image you're expecting to get with such a small circle. However, your situation isn't helped either by using fractional pixel locations or defining the circle with odd dimensions.

For a graphic of the size you desire, something like the following is about as smooth as you're ever going to get.

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="30" >
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Nazaj na začetno stran"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="border" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Width="24" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            <Path Width="12" Height="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Data="M 1,2 L 0,1 L 1,0 M 0,1 L 2,1" Stretch="Fill" />
                        </Grid>
                            
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Fill" Value="DarkOrange" />
                             </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Which generates the following (zoomed 10x)

[image]

---

For contrast, this is a 24 pixel wide, 2 pixel pen width, circle drawn with paint.net (again zoomed 10x)

[image]

Comment: thanks for response. Your suggestion doesn't seem to produce sharper circle, at least on my screen. Output is same as before. But looks like that's about It in WPF, or I need a new PC monitor :)

Comment: I challenge you to find any graphics tool that will produce a "sharp" circle 24 pixels wide.

Comment: when I think a bit - you're absolutely right. I just thought that I was missing something. Your answer is accepted, and I won't delete It. Maybe someone in future will search for same thing :)